Group actions on ringed topological spaces
Letting $(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})$ be a ringed topological space, and $G$ a group of automorphisms on $X$, I'm confused on how an element $g\in G$ is supposed to act on an abelian group $\mathcal{O}_{X}(U)$ for an open subset $U$ of $X$. In particular, I'm stuck on Qing Liu's Algebraic Geometry Chapter 2, Exercise 2.13, which mentions that $G$ must somehow act on a ring $\mathcal{O}_{X}(p^{-1}(V))$ for an open set $V\subseteq X/G$ endowed with the quotient topology, where $p:X\mapsto X/G$ is the canonical map.

It doesn't necessarily act on $\mathscr{O}_X((U)$ for general $U$, only for those $U$ which are invariant under the $G$-action (and those are exactly the open sets of the form $p^{-1}(V)$).

$G$ doesn't act on $O_X(U)$ for arbitrary subsets $U$; part of the definition of $G$ being a group of automorphisms of $X$, respecting the ringed space structure, should involve a family of maps $g : O_X(U) \to O_X(gU)$ (or something like that, maybe with some inverses inserted). These only descend to actions on $O_X(U)$ itself if $U$ is $G$-invariant, which is the case if $U$ is pulled back from the quotient.

For any map of ringed spaces $f:X\to Y$ and any open set $W\subset Y$, we have an induced map $\mathcal{O}_Y(W)\to \mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}(W))$ (ref Stacks 0090). Now apply this to the situation where both topological spaces are $X$, the map is $\phi_g$, translation by $g$, and $W=U\subset X$ is invariant under the action of $g$ to get an induced map $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\to\mathcal{O}_X(\phi_g^{-1}(U))=\mathcal{O}_X(U)$.

What is the induced map for the quotient map $X\mapsto X/G$?

@Noah it's the inclusion of the $G$-invariant sections. If $W\subset X/G$ is open, then the preimage $U\subset X$ is $G$-stable, and $\mathcal{O}_Y(W)$ is the $G$-invariants of $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$.
